# If I configure my vault for cloud save, will the game require me to be online?

Tags: fallout-shelter

If I update Fallout Shelter and configure for the new cloud save feature, how will the game react if I'm not online?

Comment: That should be super easy for you to test.  Turn off your WiFi and Data and run Fallout Shelter...

Comment: @Nelson Problem is, offline play is pretty critical to me. I don't want to upgrade if the game will only function online.

Comment: Can you not disable cloud save on a cloud enabled vault?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can continue playing offline as the saves are stored locally on your device in the same place as before.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see the game loads just fine.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You may play offline, but the cloud save version will only be updated when you are online.